# smooth scroll to last tab in android horizontalscrollview

Tags: android, android-layout, horizontal-scrolling, android-scrollview

I have eight tabs at bottom in the layout with horizontal scrollview.

Now what i want is at the start of that activity, i want to scroll whole tabs to last tab smoothly. so how can it be possible to scroll smoothly first tab to last tab in horizontal scrollview.

This is my layout file:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@drawable/divider_tab" />

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

I have tried few codes like:

```
final HorizontalScrollView sv = (HorizontalScrollView)findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView);
sv.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        sv.fullScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_RIGHT);
    }
});
```

please help me to make this animation or scroll possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have also made 9 tabs in my activity at the bottom of the screen.And I can scroll through all the tabs very smoothly.Try the below code in you XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" -->

<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <!-- <View -->
        <!-- android:layout_width="fill_parent" -->
        <!-- android:layout_height="0.5dip" -->
        <!-- android:background="#000" /> -->

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:background="#696969" />

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="0dip" />
        </HorizontalScrollView>

        <!-- <View -->
        <!-- android:layout_width="fill_parent" -->
        <!-- android:layout_height="2dip" -->
        <!-- android:background="#000" /> -->

    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Hope it helps..